# How to get array of nested relations into single Array in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Item Model:

```
public function item_makes(){
     return $this->hasMany(ItemMake::class,'item_id','id');
}
```

In ItemMake Model :

```
public function make(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Make::class,'make_id','id');
}
```

I need to get array of all make based on item_id. How to achieve this? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
$item = Item::findOrFail(1)
         ->item_makes()
         ->with('make')
         ->get()
         ->pluck('make')
         ->flatten()
         ->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Item::findOrFail(1)
    ->with('item_makes.make')
    ->get()
    ->pluck('make')
    ->flatten()
    ->toArray()
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir :)

Comment: You can also use `whereHas` method from Make model. This way, you wouldn't need to flatten or pluck.

Comment: I agree, but then you would also need a subquery to only get makes that belong to item_makes of an item with the given id.

Answer (score 1):

Try `wherehas` method something like this

```
$makes = Make::whereHas('item_makes', function ($query) use($item_id) {
   $query->where('item_id',  $item_id);
})->get();
```